# antlr 4.10.1 for JavaScript doesn't seem to have a buildParseTrees property

Tags: javascript, antlr

I'm using MacOS with antlr installed with brew to generate a parser for Creole in JavaScript. It appears to correctly generate all the files but there is no sign of the `buildParseTrees` property... most examples look something like this:

```
const lexer = new CreoleLexer(input)
const tokens  = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
const parser = new CreoleParser(tokens);
parser.buildParseTrees = true;
const tree = parser.document();
```

but `buildParseTrees` is not a property generated on my parser. Both the generator and the JavaScript runtime are using 4.10.1. Has the documentation not been updated or am I missing something (an option)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `buildParseTrees` property is defined in the [base `Parser.js` class](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/JavaScript/src/antlr4/Parser.js#L40) which your generated parser extends. But `true` is the default value, so you can just remove the line `parser.buildParseTrees = true;`.